# Cut the character between the double quotes ("") using unix command

Tags: unix

I want to cut the characters placed between double quotes using unix command batch script.

`Ex:`

String:
"sfgjskhf, jhsdf{}, sjkfhjsgdfsf, CN=jkshfks",hjgsdfhsdf,fsjkhdf

Expected output:
,hjgsdfhsdf,fsjkhdf

Kindly help.

Thanks in advance,

Sandeep

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
cut -d"\"" -f 3
```

is the simplest way

Answer (score 0):

with sed if only one pair of "" exists:

```
echo '"sfgjskhf, jhsdf{}, sjkfhjsgdfsf, CN=jkshfks",hjgsdfhsdf,fsjkhdf' | sed 's/\(.*\)".*"\(.*\)/\1\2/'
```

,hjgsdfhsdf,fsjkhdf

to remove all strings in "" in line

```
echo 'abcd"delete" abcd "and this" bye' | sed ':a s/\(.*\)".*"\(.*\)/\1\2/; ta'
```

abcd abcd  bye